# React project build errors

Tags: asp.net-core, react-redux

Hi I was trying to create a react based project , but I'm getting errors during initial build.

> 1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: ChatApp, Configuration: Debug
>   Any CPU ------    1>ChatApp ->
>   C:\Users\hirplk\Desktop\Voice\ChatApp\ChatApp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\ChatApp.dll
>     1>v8.12.0   1>Performing first-run Webpack build...     1>module.js:550
>     1>    throw err;    1>    ^     1>  1>EXEC : error : Cannot find module
>   'C:\Users\hirplk\Desktop\Voice\ChatApp\ChatApp\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js'
>     1>    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)    1>
>   at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)   1>    at
>   Function.Module.runMain (module.js:694:10)    1>    at startup
>   (bootstrap_node.js:204:16)    1>    at bootstrap_node.js:625:3
>     1>C:\Users\hirplk\Desktop\Voice\ChatApp\ChatApp\ChatApp.csproj(33,5):
>   error MSB3073: The command "node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js
>   --config webpack.config.vendor.js" exited with code 1.    1>Done building project "ChatApp.csproj" -- FAILED.     ========== Rebuild All:
>   0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

I'm trying to create the React project using '.Net Core 2.0'. Can someone please tell me what I'm missing here

Comment: error : Cannot find module 'C:\Users\hirplk\Desktop\Voice\ChatApp\ChatApp\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js' 

have you installed webpack ?

Comment: No I didn't . Do I need to use this
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebPackTaskRunner

Comment: Try `npm i webpack`

Comment: Is there a specific path that I need to point to install this?

Comment: No. You should do it in (probably) your working directory. Do `cd C:\Users\hirplk\Desktop\Voice\ChatApp\ChatApp\ `
 and then `npm i webpack`

Comment: Still I'm getting the same errors.... :(

Comment: May you please provide your webpack.js and your project tree?

Comment: I retried this and loaded the project bk. Everything working fine now. Million thanks. Please provide this as an answer.

Comment: Great! I'm glad we have found solution :)

Comment: Having a small another issue. Do I need to do this, project by project? Isn't there a global way to do this? Because i did not find this as a necessary step in any tutorial

Comment: I'm not fully understand how is your project structured and what you are trying to achieve. So, I'm not a 100% sure. Here is a way to install some node_modules globally: `npm i -g webpack`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do it in (probably) your working directory. `Do cd C:\Users\hirplk\Desktop\Voice\ChatApp\ChatApp\` and then `npm i webpack`